# Binary operation on empty set?

Tags: binary-operations

Can we techniclly declare a binary operation on an empty set?

Since binary operation does an action on some objects (which empty set dot have)...

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible, but not really useful. `;-)` Unary, binary, ternary and so on operations are unique on the empty set. On the other hand, no nullary operation is possible on it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can.  A binary operation on $A$ is a function $A\times A \to A$.

When $A=\emptyset$ we have $\emptyset\times\emptyset=\emptyset$ so a binary operation on $\emptyset$ is a function $\emptyset\to\emptyset$.  There is exactly one such function, the empty function.

As for why there is an "empty function" $\emptyset\to\emptyset$ remember that a function $X\to Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ satisfying certain axioms.  One can see that the empty subset of $\emptyset\times\emptyset$ satisfies these axioms.